# Getting the first element of a tuple, in a list of tuples

Tags: haskell, graph

I'm currently working with graphs in Haskell, where a graph is a list of tuples:

`type Graph = [(Node, Node)]`

And I need to make a list of all the nodes contained in the graph, my idea was to take the first element of each tuple and then just remove the duplicates with rmdup. I'm really stuck here and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a graph in variable x, use

```
nub $ (map fst x) ++ (map snd x)
```

`map fst x` gets all the nodes in the first element of the tuples, similar with `snd`.  `(++)` concatinates them all together, and nub removes duplicates.

Comment: You see, he didn't need the second elements of the tuples :)

Comment: @MihaiMaruseac- It isn't clear to me....  He said "all Nodes".  Is it because it is obvious to those who deal with graphs that any (a, b) link needs a corresponding (b, a) link?

Comment: "my idea was to take the first element of each tuple and then just remove the duplicates with rmdup."

Comment: @jon- Can you clarify....  Does the "all the nodes" trump the "take the first element", or vice versa?

Comment: @MihaiMaruseac The OP didn't make it clear if it's safe to assume that for every (a, b) there's also an (b, a) in the Graph. If we had the following graph `[(1, 2)]`, then clearly just looking to the first element wouldn't catch all nodes. jamshidh's solution works regardless of the assumption being true or not.

Comment: Fine, be it that way.

Answer (score 3):

When you have a list of elements of type `t` (that is `[t]`) to apply a function over each elements of the list (say with signature `t -> b`) you need to use `map`:

Now, turning to [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) and fitting pieces together we have:

- I have a list of type `[(Node, Node)]`, let's say `[(a, a)]`
- I want as a result something of type `[a]`.
- We'll need a function to get from type `[t1]` to type `[t2]`. [Searching](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5Bt1%5D+-%3E+%5Bt2%5D) we get to `map :: (t1 -> t2) -> [t1] -> [t2]`
- Now we need the function in `map`. Putting the above toghether we get that `t1 = (a, a)` while `t2 = a` so we'll need a function `(a, a) -> a`. [Searching](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a%2C+a%29+-%3E+a) we get to `fst`

Putting everything in place: `map fst list`. Then, to remove duplicates you use the same searching approach and reach `nub`.